# Alternative to Google Timezone API (Node.js or Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Google Timezone API right now but it has gotten too expensive. I'm using it in the backend and wanted to find either a free API or offline package that returns these three things (timeZoneName, rawOffset, dstOffset) like the example of desired output below.

My current inputs are coordinates and a timestamp so that'd be amazing if that existed too. Any recommendations would be amazing! Thank You

```
{
 "dstOffset" : 0,
 "rawOffset" : -28800,
 "status" : "OK",
 "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
 "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

*However I can get away without having `timeZoneId`*

my input looks like this:

```
location=${latitude},${longitude}&timestamp=${timestamp}
```

So latitude, longitude, and timestamps

Comment: What's your exact input? mention in your question.